# Get updated VerticalOffset of ScrollViewer after ChangeView()

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp, scrollviewer

While trying to scroll to the bottom of ListView using ListView's ScrollViewer like:

```
ScrollViewer.ChangeView(null, ScrollViewer.ScrollableHeight, null);
```

Due to virtualization, the bottom gets rendered on the scroll and bottom is pushed further more so there is some more left to scroll.
I tried replacing ScrollableHeight with ExtentHeight like:

```
ScrollViewer.ChangeView(null, ScrollViewer.ExtentHeight , null);
```

Still it doesn't help.

So I tried to check if the ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset has reached the expected height, else again I am performing the ChangeView(). Here is the code:

```
while(ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset != ScrollViewer.ScrollableHeight)
{
   ScrollViewer.ChangeView(null, ScrollViewer.ScrollableHeight, null);
   ScrollViewer.UpdateLayout();
}
```

Here the problem is the ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset isn't updated by the change view. Tried UpdateLayout too but still doesn't work.

Is there any way to refresh the value of ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset after scroll?

**Update:**
Sample ListView code

```
<ListView x:Name="PicturesLV"
      ItemsSource="{x:Bind PicturesCollection, Mode=OneWay}"
      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:PicturesBObj">
              <local:PicturesListViewItemControl PictureInstance="{x:Bind}"/>
          </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <ListView.Footer>
          <TextBlock x:Name="BottomMostPartTb" Text="Bottom"/>
      </ListView.Footer>
</ListView>
```

I used this `PicturesLV.ScrollIntoView(PicturesLV.Footer)` to scroll to the bottom. Since the pictures get rendered after scroll to bottom, the BottomMostPartTb gets pushed further below

Is there any way to hold the scrolled position irrespective of rendering and virutalization?

Comment: Hi, do you want the `ListView` to scroll to the specified item position? `ListView` provides `ScrollIntoView` method, you can pass in the items in the bound data collection, `ListView` will scroll to the specified position, if you need to know the detailed operation process, please let me know.

Comment: Since I want to scroll to the bottom or last item of the ListView, I placed a UI element in the footer section of ListView and tried LV.ScrollIntoView(LV.Footer)
Unfortunately this too doesn't work as virtualization and rendering of in between items pushes this futher to the bottom

Comment: I could use ScrollIntoView but the problem is, the scroll doesn't hold there. Is there any way to hold the scrolled position irrespective of rendering and virutalization?

Comment: Hi, `ListView.ScrollInToView` works according to the bound data collection (`ListView.ItemsSource`). Do you use bindings in `ListView` to create items? If so, can you show some relevant code, which is very helpful for me to analyze your problem.

Comment: Hi @RichardZhang-MSFT, updated sample ListView code.

Comment: If your user control loads pictures asynchronously, this can cause problems when the control calculates the height. You can try to choose to scroll to the last item of the data set instead of Footer. In addition, if you have obtained the `ScrollViewer` inside the `ListView`, you can listen to the `ScrollViewer.ViewChanged` event, which is triggered when the `ScrollViewer` scrolls, and you can update the scroll value accordingly.

Comment: Thank you @RichardZhang-MSFT , I used 'ViewChanged' to determine and update the scroll value. For now this is the only way to achieve what I expected.